# Airflow Cluster Policy not taking effect

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm attempting to use a Cluster Policy in Airflow 1.9.  I followed the instructions in the official documentation, but it doesn't seem to be taking effect.

In my file at `$AIRFLOW_HOME/config/airflow_local_settings.py`, I've defined the method as the docs instructed and it has the following signature:

```
def policy(task_instance):
```

Additional concerns:

- What Airflow component is actually running the policy code (is it the scheduler)?
- Is there a recommended way to unit test cluster policy code?  If not, what about local testing?

**Can anyone help me understand why this Cluster Policy isn't taking effect?**

I'm using Airflow 1.9.

Comment: Is airflow_local_settings.py in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Hmm, when I check via (os.environ['PYTHONPATH']), looks like I don't even have PYTHONPATH set.  Should I be setting that explicitly.

Comment: Yup that would explain why. You need to have airflow_local_settings.py present in your PYTHONPATH for it to get picked up. You can set it globally on your Airflow instance or add that env var when invoking your airflow commands (e.g. `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/dir/ airflow scheduler`).

Answer (score 0):

So you seem to have the file in the right place according to the documents: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/docs/concepts.rst#where-to-put-airflow_local_settingspy

And your signature is right: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#mutate-tasks-after-dag-loaded

But you haven't shown what you did and how that "did not work".

I believe the `def policy(task):` signature is run on the scheduler after DAG parsing (as the docs seem to say) while the `def task_instance_mutation_hook(ti):` signature is run by the task executor on the worker. That's probably why you're not seeing some changes take.

EG `timeout` or `queue` is something the scheduler enforces, but `connection ID` is something the worker needs to know during execution.

So if what you wanted to work was a timeout policy, it should have, but if what you wanted to work was a connection ID enforcement, that wouldn't have.